# Given a specific datetime, how do I subtract it by day?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I'm aware of how to subtract the current date from a day `datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=n_days)`,  but how do I subtract a **specific day** (datetime format) from a number of days?

Thanks in advance.

I tried subtracting the datetime directly from timedelta(days=n_days), but it gave a type error.

what I got:

```
difference = a_datetime - timedelta(days=n_days)
```

but it gave a type error.

expected result

```
difference = something - timedelta(days=n_days)
```

should result the date n days from date *something*

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], so we can see the actual input, the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: Can you post your error?

Answer (score 1):

Below code works:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.date(2019, 1, 23)
print dt
new_dt = dt - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print new_dt
```

**Output**:

```
2019-01-23
2019-01-22
```

**Speculation**: You seem to be missing a `datetime` before `timedelta` in your code

Comment: I thought this was what OP was asking too, except they've clarified he knows that that's what they're trying to do - in terms of the missing _datetime_, I'd assume they did _from datetime import *_ - they're asking to subtract a _date_ from a _number of days_. See my answer.

Comment: But, he clearly states: 'difference = a_datetime - timedelta(days=n_days)' this is what he intended to do. I am also a little confused.

Comment: rereading it, it does seem as though you've provided what he's looking for. Upvoted.

Comment: @Lordfirespeed, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to subtract a *datetime* from a number of days? Think about it: You're trying to do:

```
e.g: 203 days - now
203 - 12/02/2019
Interpret current date as days?
203 - 737510.75
= -737307.75
```